can't get ProFTPD to serve up sftp
I installed ProFTPD by doing sudo apt install proftpd, updated my /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf file to hopefully serve up on port 2222 (the contents of that file are at the bottom of this post), and then started it up by doing sudo systemctl restart proftpd but am still unable to connect to when doing sftp -oPort=2222 neubert@localhost. Doing so gets me this error:
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused
Connection closed.
Connection closed

Any ideas?
#
# /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf -- This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file.
# To really apply changes, reload proftpd after modifications, if
# it runs in daemon mode. It is not required in inetd/xinetd mode.
#

# Includes DSO modules
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

# Set off to disable IPv6 support which is annoying on IPv4 only boxes.
UseIPv6 on
# If set on you can experience a longer connection delay in many cases.
<IfModule mod_ident.c>
  IdentLookups off
</IfModule>

ServerName "Debian"
# Set to inetd only if you would run proftpd by inetd/xinetd/socket.
# Read README.Debian for more information on proper configuration.
ServerType standalone
DeferWelcome off

# Disable MultilineRFC2228 per https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/1085
# MultilineRFC2228on
DefaultServer on
ShowSymlinks on

TimeoutNoTransfer 600
TimeoutStalled 600
TimeoutIdle 1200

DisplayLogin welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .message true
ListOptions "-l"

DenyFilter \*.*/

# Use this to jail all users in their homes 
# DefaultRoot~

# Users require a valid shell listed in /etc/shells to login.
# Use this directive to release that constrain.
# RequireValidShelloff

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port 21

# In some cases you have to specify passive ports range to by-pass
# firewall limitations. Ephemeral ports can be used for that, but
# feel free to use a more narrow range.
# PassivePorts 49152 65534

# If your host was NATted, this option is useful in order to
# allow passive tranfers to work. You have to use your public
# address and opening the passive ports used on your firewall as well.
# MasqueradeAddress 1.2.3.4

# This is useful for masquerading address with dynamic IPs:
# refresh any configured MasqueradeAddress directives every 8 hours
<IfModule mod_dynmasq.c>
# DynMasqRefresh 28800
</IfModule>

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances 30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User proftpd
Group nogroup

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
# (second parm) from being group and world writable.
Umask 022 022
# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
AllowOverwrite on

# Uncomment this if you are using NIS or LDAP via NSS to retrieve passwords:
# PersistentPasswd off

# This is required to use both PAM-based authentication and local passwords
# AuthOrder mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c

# Be warned: use of this directive impacts CPU average load!
# Uncomment this if you like to see progress and transfer rate with ftpwho
# in downloads. That is not needed for uploads rates.
#
# UseSendFile off

TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log

# Logging onto /var/log/lastlog is enabled but set to off by default
#UseLastlog on

# In order to keep log file dates consistent after chroot, use timezone info
# from /etc/localtime.  If this is not set, and proftpd is configured to
# chroot (e.g. DefaultRoot or <Anonymous>), it will use the non-daylight
# savings timezone regardless of whether DST is in effect.
#SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime

<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
</IfModule>


# Delay engine reduces impact of the so-called Timing Attack described in
# http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/11430/discuss
# It is on by default. 
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine off
ControlsMaxClients 2
ControlsLog /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval 5
ControlsSocket /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>

#
# Alternative authentication frameworks
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/ldap.conf
#Include /etc/proftpd/sql.conf

#
# This is used for FTPS connections
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/tls.conf

#
# This is used for SFTP connections
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/sftp.conf

#
# This is used for other add-on modules
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/dnsbl.conf
#Include /etc/proftpd/geoip.conf
#Include /etc/proftpd/snmp.conf

#
# Useful to keep VirtualHost/VirtualRoot directives separated
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/virtuals.conf

# A basic anonymous configuration, no upload directories.

# <Anonymous ~ftp>
#   User ftp
#   Group nogroup
#   # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
#   UserAlias anonymous ftp
#   # Cosmetic changes, all files belongs to ftp user
#   DirFakeUser on ftp
#   DirFakeGroup on ftp
# 
#   RequireValidShell off
# 
#   # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
#   MaxClients 10
# 
#   # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, and '.message' displayed
#   # in each newly chdired directory.
#   DisplayLogin welcome.msg
#   DisplayChdir .message
# 
#   # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
#   <Directory *>
#     <Limit WRITE>
#       DenyAll
#     </Limit>
#   </Directory>
# 
#   # Uncomment this if you're brave.
#   # <Directory incoming>
#   #   # Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
#   #   # (second parm) from being group and world writable.
#   #   Umask022  022
#   #   <Limit READ WRITE>
#   #     DenyAll
#   #     </Limit>
#   #       <Limit STOR>
#   #         AllowAll
#   #     </Limit>
#   # </Directory>
# 
# </Anonymous>

# Include other custom configuration files
# !! Please note, that this statement will read /all/ file from this subdir,
# i.e. backup files created by your editor, too !!!
# Eventually create file patterns like this: /etc/proftpd/conf.d/*.conf
# 
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/

<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
    SFTPEngine on
    SFTPLog /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log

    Port 2222
    
    # Configure both the RSA and DSA host keys, using the same host key
    # files that OpenSSH uses.
    SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    
    SFTPAuthMethods password
    
    SFTPCompression delayed
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

There isn't a /etc/proftpd/authorized_keys/ directory.
My /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log is empty. /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key doesn't exist, however, /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key does and it starts off with -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----. To view that file, however, I need to do sudo.

I wonder if wrapping the SFTP configuration in "VirtualHost" tags is preventing SFTP from binding - what happens if you remove / comment out the VirtualHost and /VirtualHost lines?
If you do only want to bind to a single interface, maybe specify the IP address of the Interface rather then 0.0.0.0 ?

Same outcome: my new pastebin: https://pastebin.com/izwUDyU4

What do your log files say?   Is proftpd binding to port 2222 (ie what is the output of sudo fuser -n tcp 2222 ?    If you "telnet localhost 2222" does it connect/show a banner?
